# CheckBox, IsChecked == false not work

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.IsChecked == false)
    {
        grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    if (checkBox1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        grid1.Visibility = Visibility;
    }

}
```

why  `grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;` not working, grid not hidden

Comment: Your question title is about `IsChecked == false` not working, yet your question is about `grid1.Visibility` not working? Which is it? Have you stepped through your code?

Comment: Try checkBox1.Checked == false instead of IsChecked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are handling the `Checked` event, which only occurs if the CheckBox is checked, not when it is unchecked. To solve this, handle the [`Unchecked` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked) as well:

```
private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; 
} 

private void checkBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked) event to be notified when the checkbox is not checked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to use **collapsed**

```
private void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

private void checkBox1_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
protected void checkBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
 }

protected void checkBox1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; 
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }else
        {
            grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }
```

There is no such property IsChecked.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess it's because there is no `CheckStateChanged` event in WPF (note the tags of the question, this is not WinForms).

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code, you can name the event handler anything you want.  And use it for more than one event.  The odds that this was *intended* are, meh.

Comment: Thanks Hans ,Its difficult to prove the efficiency, when things are not intended that way. :)